# UniversalApiContract version for UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

My UWP app targets Windows 10 Build 10586 and contains a `WebView` XAML-control. However, meanwhile the UniversalApiContract 3.0.0.0 is available on this target configuration, the compiler resolves the `WebView` to the assembly UniversalApiContract with version 2.0.0.0. This version of the control has several shortcomings such as the lack of support for local files through the `ms-appdata:///` protocol.

How do I change this and force the compiler to use the newer version? In the references, I only get the message that this is a UWP app and therefore all UWP is already registered as references, no configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out by myself: I was using a UWP library where the target version was set to Build 10586. Even though the target version of the app was set to Build 14393 (Windows Anniversary), this made the compiler to use the old libraries.

The solution was therefore to set the target version of all components to Windows 10 Anniversary, even though the minimum version is still Build 10586.